# Парсинг JSON на JAVA, JSONArray, вложенные массивы, [ [

Tags: java, json, парсер

Здравствуйте. Фрагмента JSON строки.

```
 {"creators":[  
  [  
     {  
        "id":"30322",            
        "professionKey":"director"
     }
  ],
  [  
     {  
        "id":"1682023",           
        "professionKey":"actor"
     },

     {  
        "id":"1876",            
        "professionKey":"actor"
     }
  ],
  [  
     {  
        "id":"31095",           
        "professionKey":"producer"
     },

     {  
        "id":"1093329",           
        "professionKey":"producer"
     }
  ]] }
```

Или коротко `{"creators":[ [ { "id":"30322", "professionKey":"director"} ],[....] ] }`
Сложность заключается в следующих друг за другом квадратных скобках. Полагаю, что это двумерный массив. Пробовал разные варианты, c JSONArray, JSONObject. В приведенном ниже коде ставил в getJSONArray(null) "". Прошу помочь.

```
JSONArray creatorsContent = parentObject.getJSONArray("creators");
JSONArray finalArray = creatorsContent.getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray(null);
professionKEy=creatorsContent.getString("professionKey");
```

Comment: Да, это точно двумерный массив.

Comment: Спасибо, нашел информацию. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24179163/parse-json-of-two-dimensional-array-in-java В моем случае JSONArray creatorsContent = parentObject.getJSONArray("creators");
                JSONArray creatorsContentFirst = creatorsContent.getJSONArray(0);
                professionKEy = creatorsContentFirst.getJSONObject(0).getString("professionKey");

Answer (score 2):

Я не знаю какую библиотеку вы используете, но в [org.json](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20160810) это делается так:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONObject(jsonStr).getJSONArray("creators").getJSONArray(0);
System.out.println(jsonArray.get(0).toString());
```